# Passing user inputs as Arguments to a constructor

Tags: c++

I recently came across a problem where i cannot pass user fed values stored in variables as arguments to a constructor. My code looks like this:

```
class Complex_no{
int real;
int imaginary;
Complex_no *ptr;
float mag;
public:
    Complex_no(int a, int b){
        real=a;
        imaginary=b;
    }
    Complex_no(){
        real=0;
        imaginary=0;
    }
```

Now in the main I have a code something like this:

```
Complex_no c;
c.Complex_no (a,c);
```

where is a & c are the variables used to store user input.The problem is that the compiler shows error stating that

```
invalid use of ‘Complex_no::Complex_no’ c.Complex_no(r,i);
```

Comment: If you want to call the constructor with arguments, just use `Complex_no c(a,b);`. If you want to set it up after the creator, you need to create a function to call it (not the constructor).

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: You can not call constructors like ordinary functions.

Comment: Initialising lists would be better

Comment: Is c.Complex_no (a,c); supposed to be c.Complex_no (a,b);? c is a Complex_no, so of course you can't call Complex_no(int a, int b) with it.

Comment: Thanks @wendelbsilva. It worked for me.

Comment: I 'm sorry that is actually c.Complex_no(a,b) and not c.

Comment: @Midhun You are welcome. That was also the solution presented by NathanOliver... so feel free to select his answer as correct. It will help if someone search for a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Complex_no c;
```

Is default constructing `c`.  Then you try to call the 2 parameter constructor of `Complex_no` which is illegal as objects only go through one construction and one destruction.  You just need to get rid of `Complex_no c;` and just use `Complex_no c(a, c);` to construct `c`.

You could also use the new auto naming convention and have

```
auto c = Complex_no(a, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you the clue that the way you are calling the constructor is not right.  Constructors are called when the variable is defined or using the 'new' keyword.  A declaration in function scope is a defining declaration so the constructor is called then.  Since your example has no parameters at the point of definition, the default (parameter-less) constructor is called.  You should use the following instead.

```
Complex_no c(a,b);
```

By the way, you are also trying to pass 'c' as an int, which may be a typo in your question.